# this.props.propsName throws undefined error

Tags: react-native

In my react native 0.59 app, the props is accessed like this when a user clicks:

```
let obj = JSON.stringify({
        sender_id: this.props.user.id,
        event_id: this.props.eventId,
      });
```

As this component is called by passing two props:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat", {eventId: id, user: this.state.user});
```

But it throws the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.user.id')
```

It works when I change the way to refer to the props:

```
    sender_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.user.id,
    event_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.eventId,
```

But the [react native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props) uses `this.props.props_name` to access a props for a component. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option is correct as you are passing parameters on navigation which are only accessible through navigation state. 
As follow:

```
sender_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.user.id, 
event_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.eventId
```

Or you can use getParam function for it you've to pass 2 arguments 
**key** as a string 
**default value** for the parameter

```
sender_id: this.props.navigation.getParam('user', {id: undefined}).id, 
event_id: this.props.navigation.getParam('eventId', undefined)
```

For more detail visit [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the react-navigation website https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

it seems that you should do something like that:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const eventId= navigation.getParam('eventId', 'NO-ID');
const user= navigation.getParam('user', 'some default value');
```

I hope it helps you.